# Regular expression - For swapping text after and before underscore

Tags: regex

I have a bunch of file names like this `a1_b2_c3_d4.png` but I want them to renamed like this `a1_b2_d4_c3.png`. I am having NameChanger application to implement regex on file names. I could not figure out regex to swap `c3` and `d4`. If anyone can help me with the regex, that will be great.

Comment: Maybe this is a question for https://superuser.com/?

Comment: `(\w+)_(\w+)(\.\w+)$` -> `$2_$1$3`

Comment: Show the code you've tried; it's unclear what the issue is...

Comment: Check https://regex101.com/r/u1IPQK/1

Comment: Here's an attempt: https://regex101.com/r/ZJlap4/2/.  Not sure if NameChanger supports lookaheads, though.

Comment: `(\w+)_(\w+)(\.\w+)$ -> $2_$1$3`  is close. But still not able to do what I want. This expression is placing the last value in the front. I want to swap and 3rd and 4th value in the name.

Comment: Have you tried my suggestion? `(^.*_)(\w+)_(\w+)(\..*)$` -> `$1$3_$2$4` illustrated [here at regex101](https://regex101.com/r/u1IPQK/3/)?

Answer (score 0):

There are three permutations to what you ask:

1. If you only care about the last 2 before the dot

find `([^._]+)_([^._]+)\.`
replace `$2_$1.`

2. If it has to be exactly the 3 rd or 4 th before the dot

find `^([^._]+_[^._]+_)([^._]+)_([^._]+)\.`
replace `$1$3_$2.`

3. If it has to be exactly the 3 rd or 4 th without dot

find `^([^._]+_[^._]+_)([^._]+)_([^._]+)`
replace `$1$3_$2`